# Limit of $x \tan (\frac{y}{z})$ when $(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)$

Tags: limits

> Limit of $x \tan (\frac{y}{z})$ when $(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)$

I converted to spherical so that the limit becomes,

$$\lim_{p \to 0^+} p\sin (\phi) \cos (\phi) \tan (\tan \phi \sin (\theta))$$

For all $\phi,\theta$. At first glance $\sin(\phi) \cos(\theta) \tan(...)$ is bounded so the limit goes $0$, however $\tan (\phi)$  gives me issues at $\frac{\pi}{2},...$ so I cannot make a conclusion. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try the limits along the curves $(x,x,x)$ and $(x,\frac{\pi}2x-x^2,x)$.

Comment: I got lim tcot t which is 1 so the limit DNE , however it surprising to me that wolfram says the answer is $0$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Lim+(x,y,z)+to+(0,0,0)+xtan(y%2Fz) @Did

Comment: Since when can one trust WA for delicate limits? (Note that "nonexistent" counts as "delicate" here.)